# Css at page affect it's layout

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am having simple `cshtml` layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TDMajstor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/_Layout.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainWrapper">
        <div id="HorizontalMenuWrapper">
            <ul>
                @{
                    string currLink = Context.Request.Path;
                }
                <li><a href="@Url.Page("./Index")" class="@(currLink == Url.Page("./Index") ? "Active" : "")">Pocetna</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://termodom.rs">Termodom</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()

    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

It's CSS is:

```
body {
}

#HorizontalMenuWrapper {
    /*text-align: center; - ako zelim da mi meni bude centriran*/
    background-color: #579cff;
    width: 100%;
}

#HorizontalMenuWrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #579cff;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: large;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 49px;
}

#HorizontalMenuWrapper li {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    height: 100%;
}

#HorizontalMenuWrapper li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#HorizontalMenuWrapper li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.Active {
    background-color: #ff7f00;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    #HorizontalMenuWrapper li
    {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Now razor page which use this layout is:

```
@page
@model TDMajstor.Pages.IndexModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TDMajstor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/Null_Body.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/Index.css?id=3" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainWrappers">
        TDMajstor
        ddd
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css for it is:

```
#MainWrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Problem is making this `text-align` (since other i cannot see) but for some reason it also center elements inside my layout (`ul, li`) plus i targeted `ID` but still it affects it somehow.

I have tried removing `text-align` line and it moves layouts elements to normal so i know that this css is affecting it but there is no logic for me.

Answer (score 0):

`#MainWrapper` is the container of all other elements. So whatever styles you set to it, they will be inherited by it's descendants ( ul, li included ).

If you want to keep that style to `#MainWrapper` , you need to overwrite it on the elements you don't want to have `text-align:center`.

See example below

```css
#MainWrapper {
  text-align:center;
}
ul li {
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainWrapper">
  <h1>I will inherit and be centered</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Some list to the left</li>
   <li>Some list to the left</li>
   <li>Some list to the left</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="some-child">
    I will be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that but why css from my page affect elements from layout?